# Using Roman Nurik's Wizard Pager example, how can I access data from previous pages in later pages?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, wizard

Forgive my lack of experience, I am slowly teaching myself programming.

I have implemented [Roman Nurik's Wizard Pager model](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager) in my app, to get the user's phone model and headphone type. I then want to query a database using these two results on page three...

I have a database query method (which is inside my WizardModel class (SandwichWizardModel in the example)), that at the moment returns every entry to my database, and puts it into a list view to choose. I want to be able to adapt this method to take the strings from pages 1 and 2 to query the database and find matches on page 3.

I've been given the following advice:

```
mWizardModel.findByKey("TITLE_OF_YOUR_PAGE").getData().getString(YourPage.YOUR_FIELD_DATA_KEY)
```

Which equates in my code to:

```
mWizardModel.findByKey("Phone Model").getData().getString(SingleTextFieldPage.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);
```

But what I can't work out is how to get an instance of mWizardModel. I've tried various methods, but I'm getting a null object exception. Feeling it may be to do with context in a non-activity class, I also tried a new activity using:

```
public class Test extends Activity {

HearingTestWizardModel mWizardModel = new HearingTestWizardModel(getApplicationContext());
String testOut;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.testice);

    testOut = mWizardModel.findByKey("Phone Model").getData().getString(SingleTextFieldPage.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY);


    Log.i("The results from before are: ", testOut);
}
```

}

But I'm having no luck with this. How do I make an instance of mWizardModel, so that I can call the data from it?

If I need to provide further detail, please ask. The example code used is here: https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WizardPager isn't built for what you want. You would need to funnel your input to the 3. page. You could do that with SharedPreferences. Be careful that WizardPager always loads the next page before it's shown. So you have to figure out when your 3. page is actually visible to the user.

You can do that with this code inside your Fragment:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        if (getView() != null) {
            // load data from page 1&2
            refreshView(getView());
        }
    }
}
```